# Symfony2 Best way to implement database translations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, translation

I'm refactoring a multilanguage website to symfony.

The site has plenty of language stuff stored in databases (product descriptions, product name...) and a language table. It looks pretty much like these:
Table product:
-id
-price
-stock
-...

Table product_language:
-id_product
-id_language
-name
-description

Table language:
-id
-name
-code

So I'm thinking in the best way to migrate this to symfony and doctrine, I've been looking into the translatable extension but I don't know if it would fit here (I'm not sure about if its possible to ad the language table into it)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I built a multi language ecommerce plateform using the [KNP Translatable behavior](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable) and it's totally awesome.

It would definatly fit into your needs. Here's a quick example of my "Product" entity and how it affects your database.

```
//AcmeBundle/Entity/Product.php
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="sku", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $sku;

    // other properties
```

Then you put all your translatable properties into a new entity called ProductTranslation

```
//AcmeBundle/Entity/ProductTranslation.php
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_translation")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ProductTranslation
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation,
        ORMBehaviors\Sluggable\Sluggable;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $description;
```

This will give you two tables

The first one with all your product information (in this example SKU). The second one will have a row for every translated instance using a 1-N relation.

Once you are done you can use either :

```
$product->translate('en')->getName();
$product->translate('fr')->getName();
```

Or even better

```
$product->getName();
```

Will use the current user locale to output the good translation.

Comment: Can you please add a sample of code to use translations in Twig?

Comment: @A.L Sure, I'm super busy these days, but I'll try to update my answer during the weekend. Peace.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [VM5's Entity Translations bundle](https://github.com/vm5/EntityTranslationsBundle).
It's pretty simple and lightweight. And it also uses native Doctrine ORM associations for translations.